# How do you pause jwplayer on mouseout?

Tags: jwplayer

I'm trying to pause a video in jw player when the mouse is not on it. Here is my code :

```
<video 
src="video.ogv" 
height="100%" 
id="container" 
poster="/thumbs/image.jpg"
width="100%" ></video>


<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("container").setup({
    flashplayer: "player.swf",stretching: "exactfit"});</script>
```

I'll be very appreciate if you could help me.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this: `onmouseout="jwplayer().pause()"` and it works.

Comment: Ok. I've just inserted that code in the video tag. The only problem is that jwplayer use only one button for play/pause(so play=pause) but for my project this do the job :).